# When will algorithm B out perform A in n time?

Tags: performance, big-o

So, I have this problem where it asks me to find when B outperforms A and I thought of graphing it, but that doesn't help at all for the work that must be shown. Here are the algorithms

```
A            B
n/4          8log(2)n
(n^3)/10     5n^2
n^2/2        20nlog(2)n
n^4          16(n^2)n
```

For the first two algorithms A and B, I got 256 from graphing both of them and finding the intersection of both, but I am not sure if that is correct.

The second two I tried to graph it, but it gave me a parabola and a line going up and the only time it touched together was at (0,0), but that can t be right...

The last three sets I have not attempted yet because I am not sure if I have done the first two right. In essence, what is the mathematical work one CAN do to solve this without graphing? I want to learn how to do it by hand, no graphing.

Comment: Ask your professor or TA if it matters how long one iteration takes (i.e. if the algorithm were `O(1)`).

Comment: In any event, the crossover point would seem to be `n` where `A` == `B`.  In other words, (in the first example), solve for `n` where `n/4 = 8log(2)n`.

Comment: We were told to only find n, for which B will be faster than A.

Comment: I think you're going to need to solve the equation to figure that out.

Comment: Sounds like Find n + 1 where A(N) = B(N) then I assume `n` is a single "execution" so we can consider it one second if we have to. So n/4 for one loop would be one operation taking place in 1/4 of a second.

Comment: I just tried to solve for n in first equation, and i got 2^(n/4)=n^8 which is not right. Can you show me the steps to get A=B. I'm sure I can solve the rest if I have a general idea of how to do the first one.

Comment: is that 8 log base 2 of n?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2F4+%3D+8%2A+log+base+2%28n%29

Comment: wolfram alpha doens't show the steps though :(. It shwos the alternative forms, but how do we get it to equal by math?

Comment: Arg.  You want fries with that too?

Comment: No thanks, but I guess alternatively we can just move right side to left side and solve for 0. Thanks for helping!